# USB Barcode scanner returns values in wrong order

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, macintosh, scanner

I have this Netum USB wired Barcode scanner which shows as BLM103 Virtual COM Port from the device list.

When used on Windows the scanner returns the read values properly, but for some reason on Mac and  Raspberry Pi for example Barcode 6415600546522 is returned as 1456604560252. There are all the right digits but in wrong order. What could be causing this?

Comment: I found a manual `gzxlscan.com/download/NT/NT-1228BC%20CCD%20Bluetooth%20Barcode%20Scanner%20Manual.pdf`. It seems the config of the reader is set by scanning command barcodes in the manual. One of those is "Terminator" and it offers CR, LF, CR+LF or NONE. It's a common issue with text file interchange -- maybe the scanner suffers the same way. Mac may use CR, Linux LF, and Windows CR+LF. Crazy, but worth a try.

Comment: I have looked into those manuals. This is the correct one https://secureservercdn.net/104.238.71.250/w7p.c1c.myftpupload.com/download/NT/NT-2012%201D%20Wired%20Barcode%20Scanner%20Manual.pdf for my scanner. 

When changing the terminator character the effect is that the scanner basically presses enter or tab after the barcode. But the barcode remains unchanged. Only way to affect the output of the characters in the code is to change the language to french. Then the output will be just different symbols e.g. !€%&&=€%&="%O"

Comment: Barcodes should be numeric. So the French scanner setting coming up as punctuation sounds like a Locale mismatch between reader and computer. You might try altering the Mac or Pi locale to be whatever the Windows one is (as that works). Alternatively, there is a support email shown, although I can't guess the quality of response.